# How can I get Firefox for Windows to stop asking me for notifications?

Tags: windows, windows-10, firefox

Sometimes I go to a website and Firefox asks me "Would you like to enable notifications for this site?" I never want any notifications and I always answer **no**, but I hate it when it keeps asking me that all the time. Are there any `about:config` tweaks that can help?

Comment: You can permanently disable Firefox notifications within the settings application

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Within Firefox, use the address bar to navigate to the `about:config` page.  Once there, paste the following into the search field:

```
dom.webnotifications.enabled
```

Double-click that result to switch it to **False**.